# Update php version on wampserver 2.0c

Tags: php, wampserver

i hope you can answer my question, in college we need to use wampserver and i have the version 2.0c (which is the one provided by the college), and the current version of php in there is 5.2.6, but i want to update it to a higher version like 5.6 or 7, i already tried downloading the php version of this website: https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en but my current version won't accept it (or the file itself doesn't accept it because i don't have the latest version of wampserver), so i would like to ask what could i do to update or add a new version of php in my current wampserver build, or is it necessary that i uninstall the wampserver i'm using right and install a newer one? Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be better to install the newest WAMPServer currently V3.2.5 as there are all sorts of Compilers compatability issues with the versions of APache you probably have. It cannot do any harm to upgrade, its free so there are no licence issues.

Comment: In order to use the new PHP/APACHE/MYSQL/MARIADB etct ADDONS you have to upgrade to WAMPServer V3+

Comment: Is anyone teaching PHP5.2 there? That version is probably ten years old and should not be used any more.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, hmmm yeah, actually that's the version we were using, if we take into account that the WAMP they recommended us was wampserver2.0c